# Convert Elasticsearch Query to .net NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How do I write this elasticsearch match query to C# .net NEST.

```
 GET /disney2/character/_search
     {
     "query": {
     "match": {
     "name.phonetic": {
     "query": "Jahnnie Smeeth",
    "operator": "and"
     }
     }
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using objecting initializer syntax:

```
        ConnectionSettings _clientSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/disney2"));
        var client = new ElasticClient(_clientSettings);
        var query = new SearchRequest<disney>(); // You're going to want to replace <object> with a model corresponding to your type, or specify the type via string
        var matcher = new MatchQuery();
        matcher.Field = "name.phonetic";
        matcher.Query = "Jahnnie Smith";
        matcher.Operator = Operator.And;
        query.Query = matcher;

        //var res = elasticClient.Search<disney>(query);
        var res = client.Search<disney>(query);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you missed one line of code where matcher needs to be attached with the Query. Here is the code that works. 
 query.Query = matcher;

Comment: Good catch, I posted it.